# Building gdb from source on MacOS

Tags: macos, gdb, apple-m1

I'm trying to install a cross-compiled gdb on an Apple M1 MacBook. I downloaded gdb 11.1 and did:

```
/tmp/src/gdb-11.1/configure --enable-targets=all
make
sudo make install
```

The commands seemed to have completed without error. All the relevant files seems to be installed when I check `/usr/local/include`, `/usr/local/lib`, etc., but the actual binary for gdb is nowhere to be found.
Ideas?

Comment: Can you pipe the command to a file or command window. It might give you some information.

Comment: GDB does not yet support Apple M1. As you found out, some things get built, but not GDB itself.

Answer (score 7):

GDB is not supported on MacOS/m1 (aarch64).

You can track (authoritative) updates on the GDB discussion lists. The link below is latest status (July 2022). Currently there are no contributors working on it, only option appears to be LLDB (which should be able to handle "-O0" code).

https://inbox.sourceware.org/gdb/3185c3b8-8a91-4beb-a5d5-9db6afb93713@Spark/