# How to run GDB on an M2 Macbook (Air)?

Tags: c, macos, gdb, arm64

Okay so I installed GDB as,

```
brew install aarch64-elf-gdb
```

Which installed [aarch64-elf-gdb](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/aarch64-elf-gdb).  Then I made an alias for `aarch64-elf-gdb` as `alias gdb="aarch64-elf-gdb"` for convenience.

Why not just `brew install gdb`? Because, I did and it said,

> gdb: The x86_64 architecture is required for this software.

I compile the following file `test.c`,

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  return 0;
}
```

With the command `gcc -g -o test test.c` and run the debugger via `gdb ./test`. This results in,

> [snip]./test": not in executable format: file format not recognized

Here is a screenshot of the whole thing happening.

[image]

Is this a configuration issue, maybe I am missing a flag?  Or, is it so that it is just not possible to run GDB on M2 machines?

Comment: As you can see in the output of `file`,  Mac OS X uses Mach-O executable format, not Elf.

Comment: I am not very C literate... Is there a fix? Can I change one of the output formats to the other?

Comment: This has little to do with C. Why not just try `brew install gdb` without all the funny prefixes?

Comment: I tried that, it gets me `gdb: The x86_64 architecture is required for this software.`

Comment: I don't actually have a mac so I may or may not be talking nonsense. Apparently gdb doesn't work on Apple silicon macs. People use lldb instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73578935/775806

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `gdb` is not yet out for Apple silicon (ARM architecture). In fact, neither is `gcc`. If you run `gcc --version`, you will see that in fact your mac is aliasing gcc to clang (Apple clang).

What `brew` is telling you is that you cannot use gdb for natively compiled code. What you are using, that is `aarch64-elf-gdb`, is a debugger for cross-platform development. In other words, Apple mac users developing for Linux, writing elf binaries. Obviously, you won't be able to use those binaries on your mac.

Addendum: The other answer is correct about one thing. Your best bet now for native binaries is `LLDB`. But you will have to learn slightly different syntax.

Comment: I did not know `gcc` was an alias primarily since I did not know `clang` was yet another C compiler. So `gcc`, `llvm` and `clang`; are there any other popular ones?  I asked this question thinking hey if GCC works, why wouldn't GDB... The real reason I was trying to get GDB to work was because Emacs has built-in support for it.

Comment: AFAICT gcc works just fine on Apple Silicon Macs. The one that ships with the OS is an alias to clang, but you can install the real deal too.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I found a github page with the code, but it seems to be experimental. https://github.com/iains/gcc-darwin-arm64  Is this what you're referring to?

Comment: For what I hear you can just install it with homebrew, but I can't verify this.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Tried it, but doesn't work. I get a linker error...  ```ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for architecture arm64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status```

Comment: AFAICT this happens when an old linker sees a newer library. Can you try using the linker that comes with the OS instead?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Many thanks, you were right. Finally got it to work by deactivating a conda environment. The linker coming with the conda distribution had higher priority, so that was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use GDB on macOS before. But I guess the issue you have is that some security technologies on macOS are different than MS Windows. You probably need some extra config for code signing and system integrity protection(SIP) so that GDB can debug your C program. To be honest, it might be complex and I 'm not sure how to set those up.

**I reckon there's a more macOS-adopted alternative** :

You can try [LLDB](https://lldb.llvm.org/) if you don't need to stick with GDB. LLDB is generally more integrated with macOS, including the ARM64 architecture. It's also the default debugger in Xcode.

There's also [tutorials of how to set up and use LLDB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_C1cvo1biI&ab_channel=MikeShah)

Cheers