# Installing gdb on my Apple MacBook M1 (2020)

Tags: linux, macos, gdb, apple-m1

My university requires the use of gdb as a debugger. I've noticed that it's not available for M1, so I'm thinking of using a VM (such as **WSL** integrated with VS-Code but for M1).

I've found **Lima** on GitHub (https://github.com/lima-vm/lima), a software that should have the same functionalities, but I don't understand how to integrate it with **VS-Code** (also required) and how to use it to install gdb. Can someone please guide me through the process?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide. I appreciate your time and assistance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install GDB on mac m1 (apple silicon)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67310123/how-to-install-gdb-on-mac-m1-apple-silicon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my answer to a similar question with a step by step guide on how to configure and use lima to allow debugging using gdb (https://stackoverflow.com/a/77876274/4502415):

1. Install `lima` using `homebrew`

   ```
   brew install lima
   ```
2. start the lima terminal from your mac terminal

   ```
   limactl start
   ```

This will initialize the linux terminal (i.e., install ubuntu image by default and activate it). Wait for it to finish the installation process.

3. open ubuntu terminal from mac terminal using

   ```
   lima
   ```

Now, you will see that your terminal becomes an ubuntu terminal and you can access all your files from there. You can exit your linux terminal using `exit`. This will return you back to mac terminal.

4. Install the needed libraries within ubuntu terminal

   ```
   sudo apt install build-essential gdb gfortran
   ```
5. Give `lima` write access to your local files (to be able to run codes and write outputs).

   a. from mac terminal do the following:

   ```
   open ~/.lima/default/lima.yaml
   ```

   In this file set `writable: true` for `- location: "~"`

   b. restart lima (linux termianl) using the following:

   ```
   limactl stop default #or name of the machine 
   limactl start default #or name of the machine
   ```

   note, that your machine's name is default (this is the default name).

Now you have your linux machine (terminal) ready and you can use gdb from the terminal.

---

## Integration with vs code

Once you do the above steps, you can allow an ssh connection to your linux virtual machine to be able to connect to it and debug codes using gdb from vs code.

1. Install `Remote Development` extention in vs code, which enables ssh connection to your virtual machine
2. add the ssh configuration of your linux vm to vs code

   a. do the following from mac terminal:

   ```
   open ${LIMA_HOME:-$HOME/.lima}/default/ssh.config
   ```

   this will open the ssh.config file of your vm

   b. copy the content of the above file and paste it into `~/.ssh/config`, which is vs code ssh config file. If you don't have that file, create a new one in the same location.
3. open vs code and establish an ssh connection using `command` + `shift` + `p` -> Remote-SSH: connect to host -> choose lima-default.

Now, you are connected to the virtual machine (lima), you can navigate to your local files by opening a new directory and navigating to `/Users/username/..`. Note that vs code by default directs you to `/home/username.linux/`, which won't have your local files.
You can install any needed extensions from vs code to the ssh (linux vm) by clicking on the `install in SSH: lima-default` option under the locally installed extensions.

Comment: This is similar to what i did, but very well explained. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Using Lima I was able to create a virtual machine inside my MacBook M1.
Once installed correctly the virtual machine, I made an SSH connection to it using the terminal.
On the virtual machine I downloaded gdb (apt-get install gdb).
Once this was done, I downloaded remote-SSH extension on VS-Code, using which I was able to connect to my virtual machine and work on a linux environment, using gdb.